# Large static data member, inheritance, and performance

Tags: c++

I'm not too sure how to ask this question. I need to store a ton of data into a vector at the beginning of the program, but only once. I tried putting that vector, `my_vect`, inside a constructor in a base class to load all the data into it, but the problem is, that data needs to be used by the derived classes that will be created throughout the program.

Essentially (unless I took a totally different approach?) the vector needs to be static because I don't want to have to reload the data into the vector every time a child class is created. Can I somehow create this `my_vect` globally to avoid this static singleton stuff? I also need to be able to iterate through `my_vect` extremely fast in my derived classes. Is putting `extern` in every file a good choice? Please forgive me for any convoluted-ness, and say if you need any clarification.

EDIT:

Heres the jist of my program. I have a vector that reads thousands of lines from text file and stores them by words. No prob. I need to do that at the start of my program and I only want to store them once. After they are stored, every class I have needs to have fast `my_vect[incr]` access to the vector. I tried putting that vector as `protected` inside a base class so its initialized from the start, but the problem was that every time a new derived class object is created it would be loading all the data into the vector again. I only want the vector to be stored once, and used everywhere. Maybe singletons arn't the way to go?

Comment: "a ton of data"? What kind of data? "I need"? Why? What does the base class do with it? What do derived classes do with it? Why is there only one vector of data that every object uses? Why do you have a singleton? Why are you **inheriting from a singleton** - this is a contradiction in terms (you presumably have at least one instance of the derived class and at least one of the base class, or else the classes are useless; so now you have at least two things that behave like the base instance...)?

Comment: Why so many questions? I can't give all 500 lines of code. (Sorry for sounding harsh, I'll make an edit explaining my program)

Comment: The questions are because your question was extremely unclear, and seemed to indicate some deeper problems with your approach and understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to inherit from the singleton to use the data it provides? You can make a singleton as the data provider, and make the other classes use it to access the data.

In fact, you don't even need a singleton. Just make an ordinary class with a static field and a static method to initialize the field. Then call the static method from `main()` before any of the threads are started to simplify the code. For the rest, since the class has no data, you can instantiate it at a tiny cost, and use it as you would any other class.

Answer (score 2):

***Singletons*** are evil. You end up facing more problems than benefits but if you still want to use Singleton are your own risk you can see **[this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Singleton.html)** for how to inherit from singletons.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually don't want to use a singleton. My question was probably misleading. How can I make my vector global so all classes have access to it?

Comment: Classes are supposed to **define a data type**. They are not simply a place to store code for organizational purposes. Why are you creating classes at all? This is very hard to discuss in the abstract; please explain more about what your program really does. But to answer the question, you make the vector global by declaring it at global scope, just like any other global variable.

Comment: "singletons are evil" is a different argument, like goto, globals and recursion; except singletons are (arguably) far less insidious than either of these. Singleton's are easy to implement badly and inappropriately, that does not make the pattern intrinsically bad.  This "answer" should be a comment not an answer, or just not said at all.

Comment: @Clifford: Not here to set ablaze any wars on semaphores. The answer provides OP with a way to use singletons as base classes(which he/she asked for in first place) so it should be a answer and not an comment.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: What is evil in that? It gives a link to what OP asks, its a well known fact that Singletons are bad if not used judiciously so whats wrong in just adding a line about that?

Comment: @Karl When create a class then? I'm somewhat new to programming and I thought everything was supposed to be inside a class. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Als:  I did not investigate the link, which may answer the question, but it does not answer it *here* - that's all.

Comment: vorbis5: This depends on the language you are using and how it is supposed to work. But in general, you create a class when you need it to model some concept - i.e. to define a data type. C++ supports OO fairly well but it it not, fundamentally, "an OO language" (whatever that means).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about encapsulating your data into another class (I'll call it Data, being Base and Derived your original classes) that initializes and keeps your `vector`? You can make Data a singleton and acquire an instance of it in the constructor for Base, which would then be called by Derived.